# Does calling JSON.stringify(obj) on 2 objects with same context always get the same string?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects, stringify

For example, I don't care the actual order of obj, I just want to know if object with same context would have same string result with stringify. My question is, suppose there are 2 different objects but have same key and value:

```js
function check(v1, v2) {
  return JSON.stringify({
    a: v1,
    b: v2
  }) == JSON.stringify({
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  });
}

console.log(check(1, 2));
```

Does `check(1,2)` always return `true`?

Comment: No. This is not that reliable. As you have pointed down the flaw in this method. But in your case, yes.

Comment: There is no guarantee to the order in which the properties are enumerated. Most browsers list properties in insertion order, with the possible exception of numeric fields, so if the objects were created in the same way, you should be fine. However, technically it is still relying on unspecified behavior, and if some crazy browser decides to shuffle properties every time, it wouldn't be against the spec

Comment: You *really* should write `function check(v1, v2) { return v1 === 1 && v2 === 2; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are hard-coding the location and values, this is reliable. And yes, no matter what, `check(1,2)` always returns `true`.

Just to add another note. If you wanna check multiple keys, this will **not** work. But in your case, this doesn't apply. So you can carry on. `:)`

Comment: Well, not really *no matter what*... You're right though. Unless you write some funky code, it will return `true` in all normal circumstances :P